# Pagination in UICollectionView with the preview of the Next and Previous cell

Tags: ios, pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UICollectionView` to show an array of images, horizontally. I want to achieve the effect like that in the `AppStore` App that displays app preview screenshots (Though now I think that I should have tried `UIPageViewController`)
[image: AppStore Screenshot page]

What I want to achieve is 'Pagination' in my image cells, so that the next cell preview is shown, though the Page size should be limited to the width of the 'page' rather than the `UICollectionView`.

I have tried unchecking `Clip Subviews` but that does not load the cells out of the view.

Comment: You can try pagefloeview for that. It is easy to implement.

Comment: HI @Manthan can u tell me what is that or can you please redirect me there?

Comment: https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView this is the link for it and you can also find that on cocoa controls. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagedflowview

Comment: @Hemang : nopes  :-(

Answer (score -1):

The property you're looking for is presumably clipsToBounds.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's a bit hard to answer this way.